# AWS Glue Job Alerting on Long Run Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, amazon-sns

I'm hoping to configure some form of alerting for AWS Glue Jobs when they run longer than a configurable amount of time. These Glue jobs can be triggered at any time of day, and usually take less than 2 hours to complete. However if this exceeds the 2 hour threshold, I want to get a notification for this (via SNS).

Usually I can configure run time alerting in CloudWatch Metrics, but I am struggling to do this for  a Glue Job. The only metric I can see that could be useful is
`glue.driver.aggregate.elapsedTime`, but it doesn't appear to help. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the library for that. You just need the job run id and then call [getJobRun](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Glue.html#getJobRun-property) to get the execution time. Based on that you can then notify someone / some other service.

Comment: Thanks! I did think about this as well. I'm hoping not to 'query'/poll the Job run, but rather use the metrics feature if possible as I believe it would reduce cost. These Glue jobs run frequently, so I don't want to have a seperate process polling the Glue job statuses if I can help it.

Comment: Since you only get events on Status update, unfortunately there won't be a way around polling I think.